# How do you display a Magento sql query as a string?

Tags: sql, database, string, magento

Magento constructs its SQL queries like

```
 $this->getSelect()->joinInner(
        array('sbao' => $this->getTable('sales/billing_agreement_order')),
        'main_table.entity_id = sbao.order_id',
        array()
    )
```

Is there a way to display the resulting query in a string format rather than printing out the huge object e.g.

```
echo $this->getSelect()->joinInner(
        array('sbao' => $this->getTable('sales/billing_agreement_order')),
        'main_table.entity_id = sbao.order_id',
        array()
    )->toString();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$select = $this->getSelect()->joinInner(
        array('sbao' => $this->getTable('sales/billing_agreement_order')),
        'main_table.entity_id = sbao.order_id',
        array()
    );

echo $select;
```

Comment: For the programmery folks, what's happening here is the select object is being cast as a string when used with echo.  Using (string) $select or $seletct->__toString() would produce the same results.

Comment: It would not contain any `limits` or `filters` applied to the query. Any idea to get the full query including `limits` and `filters`?

Answer (score 6):

I nearly had it for those interested you need to use ->__toString() e.g.

```
echo $this->getSelect()->joinInner(
    array('sbao' => $this->getTable('sales/billing_agreement_order')),
    'main_table.entity_id = sbao.order_id',
    array()
)->__toString()
```

Comment: echo is just enough as it has it's own toString method

Comment: and sometimes you need to cast it to trigger the `__toString` method automatically. Something like `echo (string)$this->getSelect...`