# Output raw SQL query from Magento collection

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have the following collection and want to view the raw SQL within my IDE Xdebug tool -

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('rp/organisation_collection')
                ->searchByPostcodeLastname($postcode, Slastname)
                ->addFieldToSelect(array('organisation_id'))
                ->setPageSize(1);

$qry = $organisation->load()->getSelect();
```

This while does show the Varien object doesn't seem to give me the raw SQL for me to check - can someone confirm what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

> $collection->getSelect()->__toString()

See [How do you display a Magento sql query as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680116/how-do-you-display-a-magento-sql-query-as-a-string)

Comment: The issue with this approach is that `limits` and `filters` are not pritned

Answer (score -1):

Try out `$Collection->printLogQuery(true);` this will print collection query.

```
Mage::log($collection->getSelect(),null,'test.log',true);
```